# OrderBy not working while using whereIn

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I made a query in Laravel 5 to fetch data. If I use a simple `orderBy` it works fine. If I delete the `orderBy` and I use `whereIn` it works fine too.

Now if I want to use `whereIn` **and** `orderBy`, the `orderBy` does not work.

Here is the code I use:

```
$options = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$objects = ObjectUser::with('users')->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where('active', 1);
    $q->where('status', 2);
    $q->where('object_quantity', -1);
    $q->orWhere('object_quantity', '>', 0);
})->whereIn('canvas_id', $options)
    ->orderBy('object_price', 'desc')
    ->limit($limit)
    ->offset($start)
    ->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"doesn't work"`? Wrong results? The query produces an error?

Comment: I tried to reproduce that but it works normally for me. Of course i'm in a different scenario, but i used the same code as you...

Comment: @Ivanka Todorova : The result a the query is good but the OrderBy not sort the result correctly while using WhereIn. If i Remove WhereIn it work fine